# Multiple Range indexing in Julia

Tags: indexing, julia

I have an issue where I would like to index multiple ranges using Julia.

I have some variables:

```
idx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
fac = [[1,2,3], [4,5]]
n = 5
f = 2
z = 2
```

I would like the output to be 1,2,3,6,7,8 when f = 1
And when f = 2, I would like the output to be 4,5,9,10.

I am thinking about something along this line but with my limited knowledge, I am unsure of what to do:

```
for i = 1:f
    idx[fac[i:i]: n:10]
end
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand the question. Try: `theoutput(f) = idx[filter(i->((i-1) % n)+1 ∈ fac[f], 1:length(idx))]`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is:

```
@assert length(idx) % n == 0
for i in 1:f
  arr = vcat((p[fac[i]] for p in Iterators.partition(idx, n))...)
  # do something with arr
end
```

The first line makes sure the `idx` array can be safely partitioned into parts of length `n`. `Iterators.partition` then creates those parts and lets us iterate through them, and `p[fac[i]]` extracts the required segment from each part. `vcat` is "vertical concatenate", concatenating `[1, 2, 3]` and `[6, 7, 8]` together into `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]` for example.